# Share static data between test runs in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I have tests that require an expensive loading of static data to run rendering test watching via `~test` effectively useless.

Is there a way to load the data once each `sbt` load and cache it between test runs?

The tests are using `scalatest`.

Answer (score 0):

Sbt allows you to [specify setup and cleanup actions](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#Setup+and+Cleanup). I have used these in the past to boot up application instances needed for the entire test run.

Comment: That would only work with an external service, not some class loaded in memory though right?

Comment: The `loader:ClassLoader` will give you access to the classes in your project. In my set up I have class with an empty constructor that boots my web app based on some env vars, this app then exists for the entire test run. At the end I shut it down. I boot up my class with: 
`loader.loadClass("com.ee.integrationTest.Setup").newInstance`, where `loader` is the `ClassLoader` passed in by sbt.